# How to display doc string of a test function in output or command line when running via pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a pytest module with the below test functions with doc strings, then when I run the pytest , I want the doc string to be displayed in the command  line for each test run so that it will have clear view of the test case.
eg:-

```
test_module.py:-

def test_add():
    '''
    This is a test function for adding two numbers
    '''
    expected_ouput= 10
    actual_output = x.add(1,9)

    assert expected_output == actual_output

def test_sub():
    '''
    This is a test function for subtracting two numbers
    '''
    expected_ouput= 1
    actual_output = x.sub(1,9)

    assert expected_output == actual_output 


>pytest
```

Output:-

```
====================================================================== test session starts =======================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.3.2, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /Users/deepak/PycharmProjects/test_projects, inifile:
collected 3 items

tests/test_module.py .
--
test_add
This is a test  function for adding two numbers                                                                                                                            [ 33%]
--

test_sub
This is a test function for subtracting two numbers
                                                                                                             [100%]

=================================================================== 2 passed in 19.78 seconds ====================================================================
```

How to do this ?

Comment: This is interesting. I wonder if that is even possible. you can use print() though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use `pytest`, I use `uinttest2` but this seems like it should work:

```
def test_blah():
    '''This is test blah'''
    print test_blah.__doc__

test_blah()
```

Also, most of these unit test tools provide a standard output format that third party apps use to display what test is being run (e.g. `pyunit` under eclipse IDE) so maybe run your tests with one of those third party tools.